Why is the split statistic in the ranger package for R greater than 1?
In the ranger package for R, the node impurity is measured with the Gini index for classification trees. I would expect the Gini index to lie between 0 and 1, as
$$ Gini = 1-\sum_{i=1}^C p_i^2$$,

where $p_i$ is the is the proportion of samples belonging to class i, and C is the total number of classes in that node.
However, when I fit a random forest, for example
ranger(Species ~ ., iris, num.trees = 5, node.stats = TRUE)

I get split values with rf$forest$split.stats[1] which are greater than 1.
I would expect values between 0 and 1 for rf$forest$split.stats[1].
